# <Head> appears inside the <body>

Tags: html, css, head

The following html intepreted wrongly.

Using debug tool of chrome, the `<head>` appears inside the `<body>`.

Why is that happening ?
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<hed>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="_css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Position test</title>
</hed>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <p>this p inside a div</p>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>this p inside td</p></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
       <div class="table">
        <p>this p inside a div displayed as a table</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
https://zoharch.github.io/position/index.html

Comment: You spelled `hed` instead of `head`, is that typo or is it really your code?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a error in the head tag

`<hed>` should be `<head>`
`</hed>` should be `</head>`

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="_css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Position test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <p>this p inside a div</p>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>this p inside td</p></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
       <div class="table">
        <p>this p inside a div displayed as a table</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your spelling is not correct for head. you wrote hed.

it will be:

```
<head></head>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `<hed>` tag (misspelling of `<head>`) is not recognized, so the browser treats it as starting a `hed` element of unknown type. Since no such element is allowed in a `head` element, the browser implies the start of a `body` element, containing all the rest in the document. Before this, it implies an empty `head` element.

In most situations, this does not really matter, since the division of an HTML document to `head` and `body` elements is syntactical and “philosophical”. The `meta`, `link`, and `title` element work normally in practice, even though the browser treats them as being inside `body`. But of course you should correct the misspellings of the `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this just copy paste this head and it will be OK :)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="_css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Position test</title>
</head>
```